# Get list of users who liked a post Swift and Firestore

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am attempting to build a tableview that displays the users who have liked the current user's posts. For example, "John Smith, Tom Jones, and Sally Hughes liked your post (display image of post in cell". I think I'm on the right track but I'm wondering if my data structure is going to make this unnecessarily difficult or if there is an easier way.

My Firestore data structure is just below. The "BmV..." is the `userId`, "-M0e..." is the `postId`, and the "Ff0..." and "nIh..." are the `users` who have liked the `post`.

```
  "likeActivity" : {
    "BmvRlWWuGRWApqFvtT8mXQlDWzz2" : {
      "-M0efUXcZy43fDVXjTvT" : {
        "Ff0CxZhQzYVHuqbnsiOKwRAB01D2" : true,
        "nIhx1SnChjapy4cbrD5sC1WIZXM2" : true
      }
    },
  }
```

My first question is if this is the best way to structure this data? Then, In the `ActivityViewController` using the following code to retrieve of the current user's posts with activity.

```
var activityDict = [String: [Any]]()
let newActivity = DataService.ds.REF_LIKE_ACTIVITY.child("\(uid)")

    //print("NEW POST - \(newPost)")

    newActivity.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
               self.posts = []
               if let snapshot = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] {
                   for snap in snapshot {
                    print("ACTIVITY -- \(snap.key)")
                    let userLikeData = DataService.ds.REF_LIKE_ACTIVITY.child("\(uid)").child(snap.key)
                    userLikeData.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
                        self.posts.append(snap.key)
                        print("SNAPSHOT VALUE -- \(snapshot)")
                        if self.activityDict["\(snap.key)"] != nil {
                            self.activityDict["\(snap.key)"]!.append(snapshot.value!)
                        } else {
                            self.activityDict["\(snap.key)"] = [snapshot.value!]
                        }

                        self.activityTableView.reloadData()
                    })

                   }
               }

           })
```

My next question is if the activity should be accumulated in an array of dictionaries like I have it? Is there a better way to organize this data?

Answer (score 0):

> My first question is if this is the best way to structure this data?

When using NoSQL databases there is no singular "best" way to store data. You'll instead store the data in a way that best supports your use-cases. And since you'll typically uncover more (details about your) use-cases as you implement and evolve your app, you data model evolves (adapting and expanding) with it.

I recommend reading [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/), and watching [Firebase for SQL developers](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s) and [Getting to know Cloud Firestore](https://firestore.video). The last one is for Cloud Firestore, but many of the techniques Todd discusses apply equally to other NoSQL databases.

> should [the activies] be accumulated in an array of dictionaries like I have it?"

If that works for your use-cases, then it sounds fine.

The only thing of note is that you're using `observe`, which attaches a permanent listener, and then append the updated snapshot data to the array. This means that if an activity gets changed in the database, your closure will get called again with a snapshot for that activity.

This is great, because it allows you to show the *updated* activity in the UI. But since you're appending it to the array, you'll end up displaying the activity twice: once as it was stored in the database when you first loaded it, and then again as it exists after the update. If that is what you're aiming for then , but it is more common to *update* the existing data in the array, instead of adding the updated data as a new item.